# How can I convert this ruby file class code to use Node.js File System Module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ruby, filesystems

I have this code in Ruby that I am trying to set up in a node.js app

```
    File.open("./my-pdf.pdf", "wb") do |file|
      file.write open("https://voices.revealdigital.org/?a=d&d=CIIDHEA1968-02.1.1&getpdf=true").read
    end
```

here is the [url](https://voices.revealdigital.org/?a=d&d=CIIDHEA1968-02.1.1&getpdf=true)

I want to achieve the above but using javascript and the file system module. How can I go about this?